# Finding a function that satisfies $xf^2(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I am trying to find a function $f$ for $x>0$ which satisfies the following:

$$[f(x)]^2=\frac1x \int_0^xf(t)dt$$

Multiply by $x$

$$x[f(x)]^2=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$

Take the derivative of both sides

$$2x[f(x)f'(x)]) +[f(x)]^2 =f(x) $$

$$2xf'(x)+f(x)=1$$

Solve ODE

$$2x\frac{df(x)}{dx}+f(x)=1$$

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{1-f(x)}{2x}$$

$$\frac{2\frac{df(x)}{dx}}{1-f(x)}=\frac1x$$

Right side becomes $ln(x)+C$, since $x>0$, not sure about the left side

Comment: The derivative of $[f(x)]^2$ is $2f'(x)f(x)$, and the derivative of $\frac1x\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is $\frac{xf(x) - \int_0^xf(t)dt}{x^2}$, which in my opinion does not help. You need to do something before you differentiate.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks. Yes I need to manipulate the expression in some way.

Comment: Taking the derivative seems to be the right approach. You might want to multiply both sides by $x$ first to find a simpler ODE. Also, notice that $f=1$  and $f=0$ are solutions.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by $x$ before differentiating? You get $x[f(x)]^2 = \int_0^xf(t)dt$, and at least the integral will disappear.

Comment: Stupid question: how do we know $f$ is continuous? Or is that assumed?

Comment: Since we have an integral, and by the fundamental theorem, I suppose $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$, which requires $f$ to be differentiable (which implies continuity)?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 $(f(x))^2$ is continuous almost everywhere since $\int f(t) dt$ has meaning.

Comment: @Abstraction $f(x)^2$ is certainly continuous for $x>0$. I think you mean to say $f$ is continuous almost everywhere. In any case, my main confusion is that every answer assumes $f$ is differentiable. That's not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

for $x\ne 0$ write the equation as:
$$
x[f(x)]^2= \int_0^xf(t)dt
$$
and derive:
$$
[f(x)]^2+2xf(x)f'(x)=f(x)
$$
that for $f(x)\ne 0$
becomes:
$$
2xf'(x)+f(x)=1
$$
can you solve this? ( it's a separable ode)

Comment: You probably mean $2xf'(x)+f(x) = 1$?

Comment: Yes Thank you. Stupid typo!

Comment: I have not done ODE's with one variable, only first-order linear and separable (dy/dx), but I'll give it a shot. Thank you

Comment: It is a separable equation. Solve it and verify if the solution is a solution also of the integral equation.

Comment: I updated my question above, check it out

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x)$ be the integral of $f(x)$. Then the equation is rewritten as the ODE

$$xF'^2(x)=F(x)$$ or

$$\frac{F'(x)}{\sqrt{F(x)}}=\pm\frac1{\sqrt x}$$ with the initial condition $F(0)=0$.

After integration,

$$\sqrt{F(x)}=C\pm\sqrt x$$ and as $C=0$,

$$F(x)=\left(\pm\sqrt x\right)^2=x,\\
f(x)=1.$$

**Unfortunately all this development is flawed, as the values at $x=0$ are undefined.**

Comment: a) you missed solution $f(x) = 0$; b) unless I'm mistaken, for $C \neq 0$, $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ is ill-defined if $\int$ means Riemann integral.

Comment: @Abstraction: yep, the approach deserves better scrutiny of the singularities at $x=0$ and $F(x)=0$.

Comment: If we plug $f$ back in the original equation, the values of $C$ become very limited.

Comment: @robjohn: what do you mean ? This is what I did in the "Check" section and I don't see a limitation on $C$.

Comment: The proper check would be $$ x\left(1+\frac C{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 =\int_0^x\left(1+\frac C{\sqrt{t}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t $$

Comment: @robjohn: you are right. By the definition of $F$ we must have the initial condition $F(0)=0$, indeed corresponding to $C=0$. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide by f(x),  you have f(x)=0 
Or 
The ode f'(x) +f(x) /2x=1/2x
And if you solve it with an analysis,  it seems to be f(x) =1 the solution.

You know with the first equation that f is continuous.  So 2 solutions f is the zero function or the one functions.

Comment: A differential equation without additional conditions usually has a function class (such as $f(x) = 1+Cx^2$) as its "general" solution. In this case, $f(x) = 1$ is only one function of that class, there are others as well.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot C!

Answer (score 0):

using both side derivative and leibniz rule you will get {f(x)-1}*{f(x)+2f'(x).x}=0 so ,in this second case you have a function f(x) which is a function of its derivative f'(x) and -2x so the function can be [- e^x * x^2]